# Problems faced trying to get device connected to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I'm currently facing problems trying to get my android device to connect to Eclipse in order for me to push files into the folders as well as push apk files into my device. I've recently just downloaded Samsung Kies and have tried until now i still cant see my device in the ddms page under the devices view. All i can see right now is only my emulator. Any Suggestions? the device i'm using is samsung galaxy s2 i1900G. Hope u guys can help me out.

Comment: What option do you select in device when you connect your device with your machine ?

Comment: Did you enable USB debugging in Development settings on your cellphone?

Comment: yes i did.. i already set it to enable USB debugging

Answer (score 0):

The main problems I face when I try to connect a new phone with USB debugging connection is that :
* USB debugging isn't activated.
* The OS on any phones except the Nexus phones are Android with modifications. Samsung and a lot of other brands modify android to get in their own bloatware and own system updates.

I had a sony xperia z1 that did not connect with USB debugging untill I went from android 4 to android 5.1.1

There is a question where someone had a similar problem and solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38171690/6296561