# Android Studio not showing connected physical device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, samsung-mobile

I am using the latest version of Android Studio(2.1.2) at the time of writing this post . The problem that I am experiencing is that the ADB instance used by Android Studio doesn't seem to be able to find my Galaxy Core Prime device (SM-G361F, stock Android version - 5.1.1). It can connect to an emulator just fine.

What I had tried (most of these multiple times):

- enabling/disabling developer options
- enabling/disabling USB debugging
- revoking USB debugging authorization
- changing MTP to PTP and vice versa (my device doesn't allow deselecting both options, one must be chosen)
- reinstalling the drivers
- powering on and off both the phone and the PC
- installing Samsung's Smart Switch software
- using different USB ports
- trying out different Android Studio versions (x86 and x64 with the latest respective JDKs)

This is what it looks like in Android Studio:

[image: Android Studio ADB]

I had installed the official Samsung's USB drivers from [here](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117).
This is what the Device Manager is showing (Windows 7 64-bit SP1):

[image: Device Manager]

Afterwards, I've also tried installing the Universal USB drivers from [here](http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/universal-adb-driver).
This is what firing up its installation of ADB looks like:

[image: Universal USB drivers]

It has obviously successfully found the device.
My device also politely [prompted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aopvL.png) me to allow the PC to connect to it using a generated RSA key which never happened with Android Studio.

The only thing I've not tried is installing Samsung's Kies software.
I really don't know what is the problem here.
Maybe I should just give up and instead use the emulator but it is a damn shame not to be able to debug on an actual physical device, if you ask me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So the ADB does find your device and asked you to confirm the RSA key? meaning the computer does recognize it well?

Comment: Not the one that Android Studio came with (C:\Users\<current_user>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools) but the one that came with the ClockworkMod (C:\Program Files (x86)\ClockworkMod\Universal Adb Driver), which is weird. The mod is using an older version of ADB (1.0.31 versus Studio's 1.0.36), though, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Android in general does not support all phones for a debug connection. I have a samsung s6 and for me that works. I don't know about the Core Prime though. However, in most cases(in my experience):

- The phone does not support the connection
- You did not install all the required files in terms of the android SDK you might have not gotten the latest update that supports more phones
- The OS is not supported - Mainly caused because Samsung and a lot of other brands insist on having their own updates. And some times they - on purpose or by accident - forget to support USB debugging for developers. 
  My tablet did not support the USB debugging connection untill it reached android 6.
- The cable is a charge-only cable (yes, those exist for some reason). Try with a different cable
- You don't have the necessary drivers. Make sure they're installed

It might be circumstantial that your phone model does not support the connection for some reason, but it is really hard to tell. The only way to get proper help is to contact Samsung customer support, but in my experience it is just a waste of time. They don't know their own products. If you try with another device it might work.

Comment: Yeah, it is a budget device, surely, but I thought it should work. Guess I was simply wrong. It is funny though that ClockworkMod's bundled ADB recognizes it just fine.

Comment: If you are looking for a device that supports the ADB connection, I know SOny Xperia z1 works, Samsung s5 and s6(and s6 edge) works. It is really hard to find devices that works that isn't a flagship type phone. Nexus guaranteeably work because it is directly from google

Comment: I don't care about it enough to be spending such ludicrous amounts (to me personally, at least) of money on a phone. I think I'll be using the emulator, it works just fine ;)

Comment: The emulator of course does work, but if you __have__ to test on a real device, Nexus and the flagship samsungs are guaranteed to work

Comment: @Polarbear0106 Having a budget phone should not be a problem with this. I have used 3-4 cheap devices and I never had problem like this

Comment: It isn't that it is a budget device that is the problem. Mainly the OS is the problem. No matter what phone you have, if it is budget or flagship, it is the OS that causes the problem. That is my experience of it anyways.

Comment: yes that can be the case as of for me I have faced this issue many times with Ubuntu OS . It didn't detect any device in first attempt

Comment: I'm not just talking about the desktop OS, it also relies a lot on the Android OS. Many device manifacturers create their own version of android which means they might not handle the USB debugging because they change the OS a lot to get in their own bloatware on the system

Answer (score 0):

After some continued tinkering I managed to get Android Studio to recognize my device. All I did was adding the path to the ClockworkMod's ADB .exe to the PATH environment variable. That seems to have done the trick as Android Studio now allows me to run the application on my device even though it is still running its own instance of ADB (located in the platform-tools folder).
It might be completely unrelated but I'm not considering undoing the modification made to the environment variable.

Here is the proof:

[image: ADB]